# Deploying new Android app after many years

Tags: android, google-play

Backstory: In 2013 I deployed an Android application using Android OS v2.2. Since then, it has gained some great statistics and reviews I don't want to let go of. I finally found some free time to re-create the same app but with a bunch of new requested features implemented and did not use any of the old source code except for a few copy and paste snippets.

Question: Is it possible to deploy a version 2 of the same app using the original name, stats, reviews, etc?

Currently my build.gradle has the following:
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since I'm not 100%, but as long as you have a copy of the "keystore" that you used for the other app, and use the same package name (com.abc.xyz) it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite :

1. Should be signed by the same key (ie you should have your old keystore)
2. Same package name
3. greater version code

Short answer : Yes

Long answer :

> Use the following checklist to make sure your new APK is ready to
>   update your existing users:
>
> The Package Name of the updated APK needs to be the same as the
>   current version. The Version Code needs to be greater than that
>   current version. Learn more about versioning your applications. The
>   updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the current
>   version.

Check the following link

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: Side note here: don't ever lose your keystore, keep multiple backups. I had my only copy corrupt once, very sad day, as you can't just request another.